# Audio file issue on iOS

Tags: ios, audio

I have 3000 small sized audio files in my iphone project. File sizes are generally between 1kb and 50kb. I copied all files to one directory and I can play them. To decrease project size what should I do? What about compressing files to a zip file and then unzip on iphone for the first run? Is there any way to combine all of these files and play from one file? What is the ideal solution?

Comment: why are you worried by the overall size or the number of files? in which format are stored the audio files?

Comment: File format is mp3. The application itself is 0,7mb. With audio files it becomes nearly 20mb.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are mp3s, there is little chance that you could make them smaller by compressing them. Indeed, mp3 is a format that allows you to obtain very high compression rates.

What you could do is reducing the encoding, and you could get a substantial gain. E.g., if your files are 256kbps, you could go to 192, or 128... another option that would provide a huge advantage is converting the file to a mono audio file.

I am not saying that all this could be done sensibly for your app, they are just options.

In any case, I would not be too much worried at the 20MB, and you can surely keep all of those files in the resource directory of the app.